# copyCGImageAtTime using AVAssetImageGenerator throwing -11800 Unknown Error for specific frames of asset

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, avfoundation, screenshot

I have encountered a very strange problem while using AVPlayer to play video files hosted on a content distribution network.

I am streaming a 966 kbps mp4 video file that is 151mb (Codec ID mp42). The entire file streams perfectly fine and there are no issues. I then try to take a screenshot at a specific time.

The code I use to take the snapshot:

```
- (UIImage*)captureFrame
{
    AVAssetImageGenerator *assetImageGen = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:_player.currentItem.asset];

    assetImageGen.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
    assetImageGen.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;

    CMTime actualTime;
    NSError* error;

    CGImageRef cgFrame = [assetImageGen copyCGImageAtTime:_player.currentTime actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

    if (error) NSLog(@"%@", error);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgFrame];
}
```

Most of the time this works perfectly except for a small time period between 56 and 59 seconds. Whenever I take a screenshot during this time period I get the following AVFoundation error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x157148e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x157c3500 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 268451843.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (268451843)}
```

This is really strange as it only occurs for that small time period - screenshots for the rest of the asset are fine.

And now for something even stranger - the error only occurs when using an actual device and does not occur when testing in the simulator.. doh! Very frustrating indeed.

Any advice would help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Yes the problem I had was that particular part of the video was actually corrupt. The post production guys regenerated the video and all was well - I'll add this as an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regenerating and re-uploading the video fixed this for me. The post production guys figured that that particular part of the video might be corrupt and after recreating it the problem was fixed